# TimeoutError while generating AWS s3 Presigned URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, timeout, pre-signed-url

I've created a route that generates a pre-signed URL to upload an object to AWS S3. It was working initially but lately, it's returning a **Timeout Error.**
Here is my controller code:

```
async (req, res, next)=>{
    const BUCKET = req.params.bucket;
    const KEY = 'myKey_'+ uuid.v4();
    const EXPIRATION = 60 * 60 * 1000;
    let signedUrl; 
    
    try{
    // Also have a configuration file ~.aws/.credentials
      const s3 = new S3({
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
        region: 'ap-south-1'
      });
      
    // creating a s3 presigner obj
    const signer = new S3RequestPresigner({ ...s3.config });
    
    // creating file upload request
    const AWSUploadRequest = await createRequest(s3, new PutObjectCommand({ 
      Bucket: BUCKET,
      Key: KEY
     }));
    
    const expire = new Date(Date.now() + EXPIRATION);
    
    // creating & formating presigned URL
    signedUrl = formatUrl(await signer.presign(AWSUploadRequest, expire));
 console.log(`Generated Signed URL: ${signedUrl}`);
    }catch(err){
      console.log(`Error creating presigned url ${err}`);
      return next(
        new ErrorResponse(
          `Error while generating aws s3 presigned url`,
          500
        )
      )}

    res.status(200).json({
        signedUrl
    })
}
```

Here are my logs:

```
AWSUploadReq: {"method":"PUT","hostname":"s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com","query":{"x-id":"PutObject"},"headers":{"Content-Type":"application/octet-stream","user-agent":"aws-sdk-nodejs-v3-@aws-sdk/client-s3/1.0.0-rc.7 win32/v10.15.3"},"protocol":"https:","path":"/dammnn/myKey_file-c6f198d6-9e91-4892-8c88-8a49e15406c1"}
Error creating presigned url Error: TimeoutError
```

It's very vague as to why the request is getting timed out. Looking for some guidance on the same. Thanks.

Comment: Is this running as an AWS Lambda function?

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't simply use the AWS SDK's [getSignedUrl()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) method? And is this the `aws/aws-sdk-js-v3` release candidate?

Comment: @MarkB no not yet, I'm running it locally.

Comment: @jarmod not really. I just work on JS so decided to go with the JS SDK. And the version of AWS SDK I'm using is 
`"aws-sdk": "^2.797.0"`

Comment: I'd consider the `s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', ...)` example I pointed you at, unless you have a specific reason to go the more complex signer route. The signer is most useful, as far as I know, in situations where you don't have an available signing method from the SDK. In this case, for S3, you do have such a [method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property).

Comment: @jarmod sure mate. Thanks for the suggestion, will consider. But I'm still curious as to why this is throwing a TimeoutError?

Comment: Me too. Creating a pre-signed URL is a local calculation. There's no need for any network request afaik.

Comment: Are you sure you're using AWS SDK v2.x? Where does `S3RequestPresigner` come from? That seems to be from a [v3 import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner).

Comment: @jarmod I'm following the doc at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html#s3-create-presigendurl

This might give you some clarity as to where I'm coming from.

Comment: Yes, as suggested earlier, you seem to be using the v3 SDK. While it should work, it's not a generally available release afaik (it's in developer preview). I would report a bug or question against the GitHub repo and then switch to the GA version of the SDK. Unless your purpose is specifically to test the v3 SDK, in which case investigate this via the GitHub issues tracker. If you just want to get this working and move on, use the correct SDK, re-write the code (it's much simpler than you have shown above, it's literally a couple of  lines of code and will take you 2 minutes).

Comment: Okay got your point. Thanks @jarmod for taking out the time to suggest. Appreciated!